# Generator is empty after initial use

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator

I have just started learning python Generator
For the following code getting a blank list

```
Aircraft_typelst = ['Boeing','Airbus','MiJ','goes']
upper_case_name = ( name.upper() for name in Aircraft_typelst )
print(list(upper_case_name))
reverse = (rev[::-1]for rev in upper_case_name)
print(list(reverse))
```

Output

```
['BOEING', 'AIRBUS', 'MIJ', 'GOES']
[]
```

Comment: A generator can only be "used" once. After the first `list(upper_case_name)` the generator is exhausted.

Comment: @Satyam Is that you want to use generator ?

Comment: yes I am using generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to reuse

Generator object cannot be reused

```
# Problem is you are trying to reuse
# Generator object cannot be reused
Aircraft_typelst = ['Boeing','Airbus','MiJ','goes']
upper_case_name = ( name.upper() for name in Aircraft_typelst )
print(list(upper_case_name))
# Instead of it you can use it as
reverse = (rev[::-1 ]for rev in ( name.upper() for name in Aircraft_typelst) )
print(list(reverse))
```

Output

```
['BOEING', 'AIRBUS', 'MIJ', 'GOES']
['GNIEOB', 'SUBRIA', 'JIM', 'SEOG']
```

Comment: ... small typo.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks fixed it